# Django Summernote clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'styles' in DjangoForms

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-forms, summernote

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku.
I have Summernotes installed on the Django forms, however, when I submit the forms I get the error:
clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'styles'

Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_summernote/fields.py, line 18, in to_python

I can edit this file on the local host and remove styles=STYLES and it will work on localhost but I am unable to edit this on Heroku.

This error also shows up if i try and edit via the admin.

I'm lost on what to try next. Thank you in advance.

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import fields

import bleach
from django_summernote.settings import ALLOWED_TAGS, ATTRIBUTES, STYLES
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget

# code based on https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor


class SummernoteTextFormField(fields.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'widget': SummernoteWidget()})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        return bleach.clean(
            value, tags=ALLOWED_TAGS, attributes=ATTRIBUTES, styles=STYLES)


class SummernoteTextField(models.TextField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'form_class': SummernoteTextFormField})
        return super().formfield(**kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        return bleach.clean(
            value, tags=ALLOWED_TAGS, attributes=ATTRIBUTES, styles=STYLES)
```

I do have this in the settings files but it doesn't do anything:
STYLES = [
'background-color', 'font-size', 'line-height', 'color', 'font-family'
]

My models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
import uuid
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from categories.models import Category
import datetime
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django import forms
from django.forms import Form
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget
from django_summernote.fields import SummernoteTextFormField, SummernoteTextField



class Job(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    pay = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    description =SummernoteTextField()
    benefits = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    closingdate = models.DateField( null=True, blank = True)
    apply = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
```

forms.py

```
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget
from django_summernote.fields import SummernoteTextFormField, SummernoteTextField

class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['title', 'pay', 'location', 'description', 'benefits', 'apply']
        labels = {'title': 'Title', 'pay': 'Pay', 'location':'Location', 'description': 'Description', 'benefits':'Benefits & Healthcare',  'apply': 'How to apply'}
```

Jobform.py

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs5.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-bs5.js"></script>

    ...
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
      <div class="section__header style-2 text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s">


    <div class="container">
            <div class="main-content">

            </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Main Section -->

<main class="formPage my-xl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <h3>Create Job</h3>
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="formWrapper">
            <a class="backButton" href="{% url 'account' %}"><i class="im im-angle-left"></i></a>
            <br>

            <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{% url 'create-job' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form__field">
                    <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
                    {{field}}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div>
                  <br>
                  </div>



                <input class="default-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <div>
              <br>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
</div>  </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `pip install bleach-4.1.0`

[github issues page: 5.x version of bleach causes an unexpected keyword argument](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/issues/477)

Answer (score 1):

The error you encountered is due to a compatibility issue between Django Summernote and the Bleach library. Bleach introduced a breaking change in version 4.0, which affects the integration with Django Summernote.

To resolve this issue you have to install the compatible version of bleach.

Uninstall the current version of Bleach:

```
pip uninstall bleach
```

Install an older version of Bleach:

```
pip install bleach==3.3.1
```